# Should create 3 squares, why isn't it?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Should create 3 sqaures,no idea why it's not. it creates 1 triangle arrow instead?

```
import turtle as t
starting_position = [(-40,0),(-20,0),(-0,0)]


class snake:
  def __init__(self):
    self.segments=[]
    self.create_snake()

  def create_snake(self):
      for position in starting_position:
        newsegment=t.Turtle('Square')
        newsegment.color('red')
        newsegment.penup()
        newsegment.goto(position)
        self.segments.append(newsegment) 

  def move(self):
      for seg_num in range(len(self.segments)-1,0,-1):
        new_x= self.segments[seg_num-1].xcor()
        new_y= self.segments[seg_num-1].ycor()
        self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x,new_y) 
        self.segments[0].forward(20)
  
    
  t.onkey(t.left(45),'Left')
  t.onkey(t.right(45),'Right')
```

It should create 3 sqaures at 3 points (starting position) but it creates one triangle that is also the wrong colour??

The code is called from the main file:

```
import turtle as t
from snake import snake
import time

screen= t.Screen()
screen.title('welcome to my game')
screen.bgcolor('white')


game_on = True
screen.listen()
while game_on == True :
  screen.update()
  time.sleep(0.1)


snakelead = snake().create_snake()
```

Comment: You never create any objects or call any functions. The "1 triangle arrow" you see _is the turtle_.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I've added the main file where I call the class functions. I don't understand, my  snake class defines the segements as 'red' in colour and 'square' yet the turtle shown is a triangle and black? why would it show a default turtle without being called?

Comment: Your main file creates a `snake` object _after_ the `while game_on` loop ends. Since this is essentially a `while True` loop, it never ends so a `snake` object is _never created!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've several problems with your code, beyond @PranavHosangadi's excellent comment about the `while` loop (+1).  You're approach to `onkey()` won't work (it turns the "default" turtle, not the snake of turtles you created.)  Your movement logic is backward from your list of positions.

Below is a rework of your two files that will give you basic snake forward movement and turning:

**snake.py**

```
from turtle import Turtle

starting_positions = [(-0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]

class Snake:
    def __init__(self):
        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()

        head = self.segments[0]
        screen = head.getscreen()

        screen.onkey(lambda: head.left(45), 'Left')
        screen.onkey(lambda: head.right(45), 'Right')

        screen.listen()

    def create_snake(self):
        for position in starting_positions:
            new_segment = Turtle('circle')
            new_segment.color('red')
            new_segment.penup()
            new_segment.goto(position)

            self.segments.append(new_segment)


    def move(self):
        for seg_num in range(len(self.segments) - 1, 0, -1):
            position = self.segments[seg_num-1].position()

            self.segments[seg_num].goto(position)

        self.segments[0].forward(20)
```

**main file**

```
from turtle import Screen
from snake import Snake

def move():
    snake.move()

    screen.ontimer(move, 100)

screen = Screen()
screen.title('Welcome to my game')

snake = Snake()

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

See if the above makes sense to you.

Comment: That's worked better. It's still creating a turtle instance (back arrow) underneath the boxes somehow.

Comment: @CAOB1, I don't get that extra turtle instance when I run it.  It might be the Python environment you're using (e.g. standard Python vs. repl.it) or you've somehow added code that invokes the "default" turtle.  But the `import` statements I used should prevent the latter, unless you've changed them.